# QT SQLite Can't get table info

Tags: sqlite, qt, qsqltablemodel, qsqldatabase

I'm using C++ with QT 5.7.0 for processing some legacy DB (SQLite3).

The DB has many tables with names `00.00.00/00:00_data_N`. I can properly get data from this tables with sql query like this:

```
SELECT * from '00.00.00/00:00_data_N' ORDER BY id
```

And I can't get column names for this table with, for example, folowing code:

```
auto r = _dataBase->record("00.00.00/00:00_data_N");
qDebug() << "Count: " << r.count();
```

I try to enclose the table name into double quotes (`"..."`), into single quotes (`'...'`), into square brackets (`[...]`), and I try to escape dots with backslashes. I also try to combine all described methods and no of them works.

How can I get the list of field names for a table with so difficult name?

Comment: Have you tried executing 'PRAGMA table_info(table_name);'?

Comment: @cuda12  as SQL query?

Comment: It returns nothing when I execute it as SQL query

Comment: Yes as a SQL query. The command should work even with the "complicated" table name - I'd run the command with a command line interface directly on the DB to verify the spelling. My assumption is that either your db-connection points to an empty datebase or the table doesnt exist.

sqlite> PRAGMA table_info("00.00.00/00:00_date_N");
cid         name        type        notnull     dflt_value  pk
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           ID             TEXT        1                       1
1           Name       TEXT        0                       0

Comment: @cuda12 it is exist. I try to print database tables with `tables()` method and I can see my table. But I can't query it's column.

I create a table with a name "a.b" for tests. And I can print table name from `tables()` for this database, but I can't print columns as well!